# Get just the File Name out of Url

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to get a substring of the .aspx filename here but not quite sure how to go about it.

So I don't want the filepath, just the filename:

e.g. http://somesite.com/directory1/directory2/SomePage.aspx

I just need SomePage.aspx

Comment: Are you looking for T-SQL syntax to get this, like 'Select {filename} From FileTable Where {whereclause}' ?

Comment: yes exactly.  I'm trying to select a substring of a table field.

Comment: I think this will work, but problem is some of the charindex is returning a zero so when it does a -1 on 0 it bombs out.  I need to handle zero cases and do not add a -1 to it  select right(Name, (charindex('/', reverse(Name)) - 1)) from Entry.  Charindex is returning zero in one case because Name is empty

Comment: you could throw an IF statement around the CharIndex function to make sure that the result is greater than or equal to 1 before processing. Makes that part quite long, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You can;

```
;with EG(fn) as (
    select 'http://somesite.com/directory1/directory2/SomePage.aspx' union
    select '' union
    select '/xxx.php'
)
select 
    right(fn, charindex('/', reverse(fn) + '/') - 1) 
from EG

-------------

xxx.php
SomePage.aspx
```

(1st occurrence of / in a reversed url; add a / to handle empty/no-slash strings)

Comment: yea tried this select right(e.Name, charindex('/', reverse(e.Name)) - 1) from Entry and get Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT functio

Comment: You need to add a / to account for fields where there is no /;  `... reverse(e.Name) + '/')`